# How can I access to the ng-repeat scope?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

My `ng-repeat` creates different elements and I need to do some operations, like creating variables, only on the `ng-repeat` scope.

How can I retrieve the `ng-repeat` scope?
How can I do something like this?

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items">
   <button onclick="load(item, $scope)"></button>
</div>
```

`$scope` has to be the `ng-repeat` scope only. Is this possible?

---

EDIT

that's the issue:

The code:

HTML

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items" class="container">  

    <div class="row">

        Name: {{item.name}}  

        <select ng-model="item['id']"
        ng-options="opt for opt in ids"
        ng-change="loadTypes(item)"
        >
            <option value="">Default</option>            
        </select>

        <select ng-model="item['type']"
        ng-options="opt for opt in types"
        >
            <option value="">Default</option>
        </select>
   </div>

</div>
```

Controller

```
//Executed one time when module is loaded
$scope.init = function(){

    //All ids on the DB        
    $scope.ids = getIdsFromServer();
}

//Executed when an Ids select changes
$scope.loadTypes = function(item){

    //Possible types for an Id
    types = getTypesFromServer(item.id);

    /*
    thisItemNgRepeatScope.types = getTypesFromServer(item.id) ?!??!! Something like this?
    */
}
```

The problem:

Ids it's the same in all the whole document and that's ok, it's works properly.

But I want to change the model for the second select (types) only on the ng-repeat scope. So when I change Id, I get all possible types for this Id, but only in the row where I am, where the select has been changed. 
How can I do this?

Comment: define a controller just before `ng-repeat`

Comment: I updated the question. Maybe now you all can help me better. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the mighty 'this' in your load(item) function is the scope.

Comment: Ah, I never thought about `this`. It's the scope indeed. I can see there my `item`. But that doesn't work either. I don't know why. I pass `this` as a parameter, I do `this.['types'] = [....]` and I can see them on `console.log`, then in the page I try to display `{{types}}` or `{{this.types}}` and it's blank..

Comment: look at angular source v1.2.10 Line 19254, they only expose those $ sign variable. function name is ngRepeatDirective.

Comment: All right so what can i do? I'm using angular 1.0.6 ...not my choice btw

Comment: I don't see why you need to access the ngrepeat scope in  view, you can always access your parent scope if you need to bind your model.

Comment: I'm stucked here and I don't know what to do. Probably it's easy but I can't see it. If you look at the code I posted on the EDIT, can you please tell me how'd you solve the issue? If you know how to...thanks

Comment: show one or two rows of items. what is $scope.type and $scope.ids? why items don't contain id and type?

Answer (score 0):

I assume that with "ng-repeat scope" are are refering to the parent scope of each individual ng-repeat loop. This can be done easily be referencing the parent scope of the current scope like this:

```
$scope.$parent
```

Comment: No I have to access and modify the ng-repeat scope. Not its parent scope. ng-repeat has some variables like $index, $first etc. I wanna know if there's a variable $scope that contains the ng-repeat scope so I can use it or if there's something I can do to have the ng-repeat scope in a variable